# Add permission to driveitem is throwing 400 Bad request error when trying to set the property "retainInheritedPermissions"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

According to this documentation - [Add Permission documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) , we can set a optional parameter "retainInheritedPermissions" to notify Microsoft if a driveitem should inherit all its parent permissions.

But when try a request with that property set I get a 400 bad request error.

I tried the following request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/drive/items/{item-Id}/invite
BODY 
{
    "recipients": [
        {
            "email": "user1"
        },
        {
            "email": "user2"
        }
    ],
    "message": "",
    "retainInheritedPermissions": true,
    "requireSignIn": true,
    "sendInvitation": false,
    "roles": [
        "write"
    ]
}
```

I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Invalid request",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-06-22T06:29:19",
            "request-id": "9eabf313-36b2-459c-88d1-921bfe379833",
            "client-request-id": "993c63f1-eb7b-33ac-2374-0796e5bd2538"
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that when I remove "retainInheritedPermissions" property I get a successful response.

Comment: Sounds like a bug https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1198862/send-sharing-invitation-retaininheritedpermissions you probably need to create your own ticket to see where they are up to with it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll be opening a microsoft ticket for this